# Undefined relationship error in sorting of existence and non existence relationship using Eager Load in Laravel eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a Student model and a corresponding one to one mapping relationship to Result model.

I have an eligibleList array containing a list of student id whose marks are to be displayed. Some student have results while some does not have but i need to display all of them from the list.

I am able to retrieve and display students using the following:

```
$students = Student::with('result:student_id,marks')->whereIn('students.id', $eligibleList)->get();

foreach($students as student) {
    if ($student->result != null) 
      Log::debug($student->result->marks)   
    else 
      Log::debug("-1") //-1 indicate no results   
}
```

The above has no issue until i need to sort the list (ascending or descending) by the marks. I tried the following:

```
$students = Student::with(['result:student_id,marks' => function ($query) {
          $query->orderBy('marks','DESC');
          }])->whereIn('student.id', $eligibleList)->get();
```

It throws me a "Call to undefined relationship" error. Is there anyway to sort from the query ? I avoid sorting the collection as it can get very slow for thousands of records. Somehow eloquent early loading encounter some error when sorting with non existence relationship.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'Subquery Ordering', ordering inside 'with' will not sort the overall result.

```
$students = Student::with(['result:student_id,marks'])->whereIn('student.id', $eligibleList)
->orderByDesc(Result::select('marks')->whereColumn('student_id','students.id'))
->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries

if you use laravel 5 you have to use 'join':

```
Student::with(['result:student_id,marks'])->whereIn('student.id', $eligibleList)
->join('result','result.student_id','student.id')
->select('user.*,result.marks')->orderBy('result.marks')->get();
```

'join' use table name not the relation name, so please be careful about table name in previous 'join' and 'select' statements

Comment: Thanks OMR, this feature is not available in Laravel 5.x Is there any work around on this ?

Comment: let me know if it helps